# Searching sembast data both caps and small letters

Tags: flutter

I am using sembast package for local data storage for a flutter app. When I search through the local data, I want to get the results regardless of whether letters are in caps or small. My current code is sensitive to capital and small letters.

```
  Future searchFoodByField(String fieldName, String searchItem) async {
var finder = Finder(filter: Filter.matches(fieldName, searchItem));
final recordSnapshots = await _foodStore.find(
  await _db,
  finder: finder,
);
return recordSnapshots.map((snapshot) {
  final food = Food.fromMap(snapshot.value);
  food.foodId = snapshot.key;
  return food;
}).toList();
}
```

How can it be modified to get the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to look for the exact word. For non-english language, you might also want to remove the accent. ([diacritic](https://pub.dev/packages/diacritic) package can help help here).

```dart
// Using a regular expression matching the exact word (no case)
var filter = Filter.matchesRegExp(
    fieldName, RegExp('^$searchItem\$', caseSensitive: false));
```

You can also use a custom filter, to perform any filtering you want:

```dart
// Using a custom filter exact word (converting everything to lowercase)
searchItem = searchItem.toLowerCase();
filter = Filter.custom((snapshot) {
  var value = snapshot[fieldName] as String;
  return value?.toLowerCase() == searchItem;
});
```